# Can the Jackson CsvMapper parse CSV with spaces in the header names into an object?

Tags: jackson-dataformat-csv

I'm trying to import a CSV file with spaces in the header row directly into a POJOs using `CsvMapper.schemaFor(Class<>)`. Naturally the respective members cannot have spaces in the identifier. Is there a way to tell the mapper which columns to map on which member?

Answer (score 3):

Just map fields in your POJO model aka

```
@JsonProperty("Property with spaces")
private String propertyWithSpaces;
```